# Hooking GetVolumeInformation to return a custom filesystem type

Tags: c++, easyhook

I've been attempting (and miserably failing!) at learning how to use Easyhook. I'm trying to hook and return a custom filesystem name for all GetVolumeInformation calls. The following code does hook and I get the filesystem name in debugview, but it crashes the app that loads it.

Any help would be massively appreciated

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <easyhook.h>




BOOL WINAPI myhook(LPCTSTR lpRootPathName, LPTSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer, DWORD nVolumeNameSize, LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber, LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength, LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags, LPTSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer, DWORD nFileSystemNameSize);

BOOL WINAPI myhook(LPCTSTR lpRootPathName, LPTSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer, DWORD nVolumeNameSize, LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber, LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength, LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags, LPTSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer, DWORD nFileSystemNameSize)
{

    BOOL retval = GetVolumeInformationW(lpRootPathName, lpVolumeNameBuffer, nVolumeNameSize, lpVolumeSerialNumber, lpMaximumComponentLength, lpFileSystemFlags, lpFileSystemNameBuffer, nFileSystemNameSize);
    if (retval) {

      wcscpy_s(lpFileSystemNameBuffer, 8, L"NOTNTFS");

      OutputDebugString(lpFileSystemNameBuffer);


    }
    return retval;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    HOOK_TRACE_INFO hHook = { NULL }; // keep track of our hook



    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {

    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {

        NTSTATUS result = LhInstallHook(
            GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "GetVolumeInformationW"),
            myhook,
            NULL,
            &hHook);
        if (FAILED(result))
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("FAILED TO HOOK");
        }
        else {
            OutputDebugStringA("HOOKED");

            ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };
            LhSetInclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &hHook);

        }

    }


    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    {


    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

    {

    }
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Things have changed since XP. If you want the hook to work your app needs to be installed into `c:\program files` (64-bit) or `c:\program files(x86)` (32-bit) otherwise Windows kernel will disable the hooking API.

Comment: Why not use Microsoft Detours.

Comment: Hi there, I have also tried with detours, to the same end! Thanks